# Whay apache2 does not process PHP files?

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I have installed Apache server using TaskSel from Synaptic package manager.

I did the following:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
Module php5 already enabled

sudo a2enmod userdir
Module userdir already enabled

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

I have created two info.php files one for my home directory public_html and another one for /var/www next to the "It Works!" file with the following code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But when I navigate to either local addresses:

```
localhost
or
localhost/~username
```

I got a blank page and when I clicked view page source I found the same php code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it, and here is what I did:

Just I had to comment the following lines in php.conf

/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_value engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

And everything is working fine...