# PHP errors in /usr/sbin/a2query

Tags: apache2, php, compiling

I am new to Ubuntu, currently on 14.04, I develop on Windows but want to do same on Linux(Ubuntu) I tried to open a PHP file from localhost, I get a blank page. I checked if the PHP module is loaded I get this error

```
usage: fail($reason, $retval) at /usr/sbin/a2query line 168.
Php5 is already enabled.
```

The console on my browser says:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

I have checked for several solutions, but can't seem to find one.
Please I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whay apache2 does not process PHP files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/296403/whay-apache2-does-not-process-php-files)

Comment: Thanks @Jos when I used the solution on the link and set my permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The white screen might be due to folder permissions...try:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/whateverfolderyourdevelopingin
```

Are you using a framework? I'm using laravel5 myself and i get the same character encoding message in console. However my site works as intended.
I'm suspecting is has something to do with the index.php file or it might be an outdated browser issue.